# Python ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. while using SVM in scikit-learn

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image, scikit-learn, svm

I have been working on scikit-learn SVMs for a binary classification problem. I have calculated the features of images and store it in array. This is how each row in a array  looks like:

```
 [variable(0.16749821603298187) variable(0.15862827003002167)
  variable(0.15818320214748383) ..., variable(0.2765314280986786)
  variable(0.2909393608570099) variable(0.2909393608570099)]
```

shape of X_train_svm is (6, 7290)  and Y_train is (6,)
So when I print X_train_svm and Y_train I get exact values in an array. But when I use

```
 from sklearn.svm import SVC
 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
 classifier=SVC(kernel='linear',random_state=0)
 classifier.fit(X_train_svm,Y_train)
```

get the error saying

```
   ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
         <ipython-input-145-a957b86fe2dc> in <module>
         2 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
         3 classifier=SVC(kernel='linear',random_state=0)
   ----> 4 classifier.fit(X_train_svm,Y_train)


c:\users\s121293.squ\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site- 
 packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     480 
     481     """
 --> 482     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     483 
     484 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Can someone help me as to what I can do now? I am really not sure what is happening inside. Both the dimensions of X_train and Y_train are same.

Note: I have a feeling that something might be wrong while I convert the object to a numpy array. Thanks in advance.

Edit: X_Train_svm is looking like the following

```
 [[variable(0.16749821603298187) variable(0.15862827003002167)
   variable(0.15818320214748383) ..., variable(0.2765314280986786)
   variable(0.2909393608570099) variable(0.2909393608570099)]
   ..............................................................
   [variable(0.22378747165203094) variable(0.22378747165203094)
   variable(0.20569562911987305) ..., variable(0.29241225123405457)
   variable(0.31552478671073914) variable(0.31552478671073914)]]
```

y_train is the label

```
          [0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

i have used the following code to convert the features in fully-connected layer  for SVM classifier

```
     X_train_SVM=Fc1_output

    print(Y_train)
    print(X_train_SVM.shape)

    Y_train_svm=np.reshape(Y_train,(6,1))
    ####### SVM ######################


   clf = SVC(gamma=0.01,C=10,kernel='poly')
   clf.fit(X_train_SVM,Y_train_svm)
```

And all my images are of same size ie i resized to 224x224

Comment: try changing your `Y_train` shape to (6, 1)

Comment: also what are the input & output shapes for your model?

Comment: ok, what is the output of your model?

Comment: the problem is that one of the model's shapes(input or output) doesn't match the shape of your data, in your case try just reshaping your labels to the shape of (6, 1):
```Y_train = Y_train.reshape((6, 1))```.

Comment: can you post post the portion of the code where you convert images to `X_train`?

Comment: and also, are all of your images the same size?

Comment: most likely the way you convert your images to training data is the problem, for reading images correctly i recommend you use `PIL` or `OpenCV`, then if your model input is 1D, reshape the images to 1D form and please use `np.concatenate()` to add elements to an array with your data.

Comment: @okawo  i have used opencv for accessing my training images from directory and i placed the code. i have used append to store the images in a list. whether i need to change it to no.concatenate. when i used np.concatenate() , it was storing only one image

Comment: to add to an array using `np.concatenate()` you do: ```a = np.concatenate((a, [someData]), axis=0)```, also make sure your images black and white or your data conversion accommodates for RGB images.